# css for bootstrap 3 for screens smaller than 767 xs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 the width of extra small screen is 767px.  I want to keep 2 columns till say 600px and then go to one column.  Seemingly bootstrap does not have this built in and whatever columns are set for 767px will be the same to 0px.

Nexus 7 for example is about 600px wide.  Most phones are 350 wide - http://mydevice.io/devices/.  Is 767 a bit wide for extra small?

Seemingly I have to add my own style - xxs, but where can I get the needed width % etc?  How would I work out needed width %?  Is there a site that can generate the css?

BASED ON @cvrebert ANSWER :

A bootstrap online LESS complier can be found here - http://getbootstrap.com/customize

The @screen-sm variable changes the xs col width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option mentioned in Bootstrap's docs is to change what the boundary between the extra-small (`xs`) and small (`sm`) screen sizes is by simply changing the value of the `@screen-sm-min` [LESS](http://lesscss.org) variable (which lives in Bootstrap's `variables.less` file) and then recompiling Bootstrap's CSS.

Comment: I wasnt using LESS but I found the online compiler thanks.  I wanted to add a new setting rather than change the rest, but I should be able to work that out from the compiler results (hopefully!).  Thanks.